# Spark SQL CLI vs Thriftserver/Beeline

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Can someone spell out the differences between using the Spark SQL CLI vs. Thriftserver/Beeline to query/modify data in Hive ? The [Spark SQL documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/sql-programming-guide.html#other-sql-interfaces) 
mentions both of them but when would you use one or the other or are they equivalent alternatives from a functional point of view ?

Answer (score 2):

For clarification:

- **spark-sql** is a program that runs a single instance of Spark and you interact with it as if it were a mysql-like shell prompt and it makes use of the spark-warehouse and those types of features
- **Spark with Thriftserver** is an application that exposes a connection to a running instance of Spark over a JDBC connection.
  https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/33715/why-do-we-need-to-setup-spark-thrift-server.html
- **Beeline** is a query / consumer tool that one uses to consume / connect to a running JDBC hive2 table (and thus in the spark documentation, they use beeline to test that the JDBC connection is in fact working). **Note:** query / connector programs like SQL Workbench can be made to connect to Spark with Thriftserver if it imports the proper Hive2 JDBC drivers & jars